# PHP - Is this good require_once or extends

Tags: php, oop, extends, require-once

I'm a newbie in php but I'll try to get straight to the point.
I have a class called ConnectionManager

```
class ConnectionManager
{
     function ConnectToDB()
     {
         //PDO connection code  
     }
}
```

and in my other manager InstitutManager I am using require_once($filename) to get access to my ConnectionManager functions

```
require_once('../manager/ConnectionManager.php');
class InstitutManager
{
     protected $connInstance;

     function _construct()
     {
         $this->connInstance = new ConnectionManager;
     }

     function getInstituts()
     {
         $conn = $connManager->ConnectToDb();
         //retrieve instituts 
     }
}
```

The question is : Should I be using `extends ConnectionManager` in my InstitutManager instead of require_once? Why should I use one more than the other?

Thanks

Edit : Changed code for InstitutManager class

Would this be ok like this? Or should I pass a pass a parameter with my connection already instanciated in `function _construct($conn)`?

Comment: If you're going to extend a class,  you will still need to include that file (have the definition)

Comment: require is very different to extends.... they serve totally different purposes, and you still need to require the ConnectionManager.php file even if you extend

Comment: Your code would also really be better setting a class property for the ConnectionManager in the InstitutManager constructor rather than needing to instantiate a new ConnectionManager for every method that needs it

Comment: If the functions in InstitutManager are a local extension of the functions in ConnectionManager, then you would say that IM extends CM. However if CM is just a generic database class, IM wouldn't extend it because they are mutually exclusive classes and it happens that IM **uses** CM but won't extend its functionality. Simply requiring it and starting a new instance like you are doing would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include_once reads in a source file, which in this case has a class definition for ConnectionManager in it. Your extends sets up class InstitutManager as inheriting class ConnectionManager, i.e. InstitutManager gets everything in ConnectionManager and can then define its own modifications to that basic structure. There isn't really any relationship at all between the two operations, and your $connManager  = new ConnectionManager operations are nonsensical.

Comment: They aren't nonsensical at all. It's common practice for classes like that to use a database class for data source abstraction - how would he retrieve his data without starting a new instance of the connection?

Comment: @scrowler Dependency injection?

Comment: @scrowler - it's a nonsense if the `getInstituts()` method has to be called several times in the script, or if other methods in the `InstitutManager` use similar code and also require a ConnectionManager, because then it needs to instantiate a new `ConnectionManager` every time it's needed.... using DI and a class property would mean that the ConnectionManager only needs to be instantiated once, no matter how many calls to the methods that use it are made

Comment: Totally agree, and it should totally be stored and checked for existence before creating it again - I just figured that this was an example conceptually - and conceptually, if a class needs to access the DB class and hasn't instantiated it already, it would be created as in his example

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks for your input so far guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`require_once 'file'.php'` just means that the PHP interpreter will take the contents of a file called `file.php` and dump it right there in the spot where the include was called. Kind of like what would happen if you would select everything in a Word file, click copy and paste it at the top of another Word file.

In your case you need to include the file, or else it will not know where to find the `ConnectionManager` class.